# Server error 500 on register form submission

Tags: laravel, nginx, forge

I have a laravel application which I have hosted on a Digital Ocean droplet using Laravel Forge. Every time I clicked submit on my registration form it saves the data in the database and displays a server error 500.

I have managed to cd into my nginx error logs using the sudo root access and have been able to come up with this, please help me out

> 1. /home/forge/onenaira.com.ng/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(289): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->renderHttpException(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException))
> 2. /home/forge/onenaira.com.ng/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(188): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->prepareResponse(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Obje" while reading response header from upstream, client: 105.112.66.215, server: onenaira.com.ng, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock:", host: "onenaira.com.ng"
>      2019/05/02 22:22:14 [error] 10655#10655: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  include(/home/forge/onenaira.com.ng/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Request.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/forge/onenaira.com.ng/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444PHP message: PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/home/forge/onenaira.com.ng/vendor/composer/../symfony/http-foundation/Request.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/forge/onenaira.com.ng/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request' not found in /home/forge/onenaira.com.ng/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php:15

**Stack trace:**

> 1. /home/forge/onenaira.com.ng/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(444): include()
> 2. /home/forge/onenaira.com.ng/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322):   Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/home/forge/one...')
> 3. [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Illuminate\Http...')
> 4. /home/forge/onenaira.com.ng/public/index.php(55): spl_autoload_call('Illuminate\Http...')
> 5. {main}
>      thrown in /home/forge/onenaira.com.ng/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php on line 15" while reading response header from upstream, client: 105.112.23.124, server: onenaira.com.ng, request: "GET /password/api/slotcount HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock:", host: "onenaira.com.ng", referrer: "https://onenaira.com.ng/password/reset

Comment: Try running `composer update`. If there are any errors please can you add them to your question.

Comment: okay i have done that and i have this:

Comment: #2 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Illuminate\\Http...')
#3 /home/forge/onenaira.com.ng/public/index.php(55): spl_autoload_call('Illuminate\\Http...')
#4 {main}
  thrown in /home/forge/onenaira.com.ng/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php on line 15" while reading response header from upstream, client: 105.112.23.124, server: onenaira.com.ng, request: "GET /password/api/slotcount HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock:", host: "onenaira.com.ng", referrer: "https://onenaira.com.ng/password/reset"

Comment: Was the an error from the console after running update or did you get it in the browser?

Comment: it was an error from the console after running update, i did a cd into my nginx error logs and got that

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: @Rwd any updates on this, I'm experiencing the same 500 server error after form submissions?

Comment: @PT-83 I would recommend creating a new question.